# How to prevent user from being able to slide left thumb in Flutter RangeSilder

Tags: flutter, dart, rangeslider

This is my range slider widget implementation, I want to prevent the user from being able to slide the left thumb slider

```
  RangeSlider(
                          divisions: 5,
                          activeColor: Colors.red[700],
                          inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
                          min: 1.0,
                          max: 10.0,
                          values: values,
                          labels: labels,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            state(
                              () {
                                values = value;
                                labels = RangeLabels(
                                  "${value.start.toInt().toString()}km",
                                  "${value.end.toInt().toString()}km",
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
```

Comment: Did you try something like ```if(values.start != value.start) return;``` inside ```onChanged``` callback ? this will prevent updating the state if user slides the start slider

Comment: no i did not, let me try that

Comment: I'll post it as answer, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `if (values.start != value.start) return;` inside your `onChanged`, this will prevent updating `values` which prevent updating the `RangeSlider`

Answer (score 0):

Comment from @ikerfah which helped was to include if(values.start != value.start) return; inside onChanged callback

```
   RangeSlider(
                          divisions: 5,
                          activeColor: Colors.red[700],
                          inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
                          min: 1.0,
                          max: 10.0,
                          values: values,
                          labels: labels,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            state(
                              () {
                                if (values.start != value.start) return;
                                values = value;
                                labels = RangeLabels(
                                  "${value.start.toInt().toString()}km",
                                  "${value.end.toInt().toString()}km",
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
```